# What notification icon is this fish?

Tags: applications, notification-icons

This is on an S7 Edge.  I do not have this phone in my possession.  This is from a screen shot of a text they sent.  This "fish" icon was in the notification bar at the top left. I have searched in reverse image and cannot get an app name.  Does anyone recognize this icon?

Thank you

[image: notification icon]

Answer (score 1):

It's a game notification from Fishdom

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on the notification (icon) you should always get a popup to the app which pinned the message!

And if you pressing/ holding the icon long you can select the app-info for more details!

If missed to clicking the app or you accidently swiped away use the [Andorid-Notification-Log](https://www.howtogeek.com/242073/how-to-view-notifications-youve-dismissed-on-android/)